Show that functional $J$ satisfies Palais-Smale condition iff every $P-S$ sequence is bounded
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and let $K: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and such that $\nabla K: H \rightarrow H$ sends bounded sets into precompact sets. Consider the functional $J: H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\|u\|^2+K(u) .
$$
I want to show that $J$ satisfies the Palais-Smale condition if and only if every PalaisSmale sequence is bounded.
My attempt: because PalaisSmale sequence is bounded, so it is weakly convergent, and the gradient has a convergent value, but then I don't know what to do

the gradient of $J$ is $\nabla J=u+\nabla K$, so if $u_{k}$ is a P-S sequence in that satisfy the P-S condition, then there is a subsequence denoted by $u_{k}$ for convenience that converge to $u$, then since the gradient of $J$ tends to $0$, and both $u$ and $\nabla K$ is continuou, hence $u=-\nabla K(u)$

if $u_{k}$ is bounded, then $\nabla K(u_{k})$ is bounded and precompact hence $\nabla K(u_{k})$ tends to $x$(for some subsequence and we denote it by $u_{k}$ for simplicity), because $\nabla J$ tends to 0, hence $\nabla J=u_{k}+\nabla K$ tends to 0 because  $\nabla K(u_{k})$  tends to $x$, hence $u_{k}$ tends to $-x$
